# display image by using uint16array data

Tags: javascript, canvas, dicom, xtk, uint16

I am doing a DICOM project using XTK library. Now I need to create a list of thumbnails from input DICOM files (output images could be PNG or JPG).

During the rendering process, XTK provides an array of pixel data in an `Uint16Array` of each DICOM file. But I have no idea about converting those pixel data into a canvas.

[image: unnecessary screenshot of what I am looking at]

I searched for some related articles or questions but found nothing possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, [ImageData has become a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData), that you can put on a 2d context easily.

What it expects as arguments is an UInt8ClampedArray, a width and a height.

So from an Uint16Array representing rgba pixel data, you'd just have to do

```
var data = your_uint16array;
var u8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer);
var img = new ImageData(u8, width, height);
ctx.putImageData(img, 0,0);
```

But according to your screenshot, what you have is actually an Array of Uint16Array, so you will probably have to first merge all these Uint16Arrays in a single one.

Also note that an Uint16Array is a weird view over an rgba pixel data, Uint32Array being more conventional (#ffff vs #ffffffff).